# Jemalloc: Java Native Memory profiling shows 100% je_prof_backtrace

Tags: java, java-11, jemalloc

We have a multi-threaded production Java application. We are trying to check the native memory usage as mentioned in this [post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/troubleshooting-native-memory-leaks-in-java-applications).

But on the dump I am seeing 100% memory is being taken by `je_prof_backtrace`

````
ubuntu@platform1:/tmp/jemalloc_dump$ /home/ubuntu/jemalloc/bin/jeprof --show_bytes `which java` /tmp/jemalloc_dump/tsdb.62634.6454.i6454.heap
Using local file /usr/bin/java.
Using local file /tmp/jemalloc_dump/tsdb.62634.6454.i6454.heap
Welcome to jeprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(jeprof) top
Total: 815965512 B
815965512 100.0% 100.0% 815965512 100.0% je_prof_backtrace
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268451840  32.9% 0x00007f1338bd83a5
       0   0.0% 100.0% 279057735  34.2% 0x00007f13390d615a
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% 0x00007f133918adda
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% AllocateHeap
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% JVM_MonitorWait
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268451840  32.9% Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_inflateBytesBytes
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::inflate
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::omAlloc
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::wait```
````

Output is like below if I use `text`

```
(jeprof) text
Total: 815965512 B
815965512 100.0% 100.0% 815965512 100.0% je_prof_backtrace
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268451840  32.9% 0x00007f1338bd83a5
       0   0.0% 100.0% 279057735  34.2% 0x00007f13390d615a
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% 0x00007f133918adda
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% AllocateHeap
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% JVM_MonitorWait
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268451840  32.9% Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_inflateBytesBytes
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::inflate
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::omAlloc
       0   0.0% 100.0% 268455936  32.9% ObjectSynchronizer::wait
```

Steps followed.

1. Downloaded jemalloc 5.2.1 release tag from [here](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/archive/refs/tags/5.2.1.tar.gz).
2. `./autogen.sh --enable-prof` inside the directory where jmalloc tar in untared.
3. `make`

Application was started with the below options

```
export JEMALLOC_PATH=/home/ubuntu/jemalloc
export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:21,lg_prof_sample:28,prof_prefix:/tmp/jemalloc_dump/tsdb
LD_PRELOAD=${JEMALLOC_PATH}/lib/libjemalloc.so.2 \
java ...
```

I am new to jemalloc. Can someone suggest what could be going wrong?

```
ubuntu@platform1:/tmp/jemalloc_dump$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.48+22-SA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.48+22-SA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

- OS - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The Java heap is not the same the heap provided by any `malloc()` implementation.

Comment: I know. Somone edited the title. I am looking to check native memory usage.

Comment: According to [this bug](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/507) this is not abnormal. Do you see stacks if you issue `text` instead of `top`?

Comment: @Botje I am seeing some hexadecimal number if I use `text`. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Those appear to be the stack addresses of your Java threads. I'm a bit confused it is not segregating the dump by thread..

Comment: @Botje Is there some issue in the version of jemalloc (5.2.1) I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring using the below flags :

```
./configure --enable-prof --enable-stats --enable-debug --enable-fill
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in [github](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/2081) also. Posting the relevant reply

> Quoting Jason from the original thread:
>
> This is usually caused by the backtracing facility failing to do
> anything beyond reporting the caller's return instruction pointer. You
> may have better luck if you use libunwind, but unfortunately I've seen
> all the supported backtracing mechanisms fail under various
> conditions.
>
> In other words, if you haven't tried libunwind, give that a try. The
> reported issue happens when the stack unwinder cannot walk the stack,
> in which case jemalloc / jeprof doesn't have any backtrace data to
> report.
>
> Closing because nothing actionable from the jemalloc side.